# Show only data based on the logged in user

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, forms-authentication

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and am trying to figure out the best practice for finding information relevant to the logged in user. I'm using Forms Authentication.

If a user goes to a page where they should view only the tickets that are related to that user, do I need to find the client every time like below?

Is there an easier way for me to save the Client that the user is connected to, so I only need to check once?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     Client client = _db.Clients.Single(c => c.Username == User.Identity.Name);
     view.OpenTickets = _db.Tickets.Where(t => t.ClientID == client.ClientID).Count();
     return PartialView(supportView);
}
```

Comment: Why not have your opentickets sql do a join with the clients table and take the value you use to look up the client as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a session variable might be a good solution if you are accessing it across different pages. You might want to look into creating cookies if you want user to save his preferences (password, local settings etc.).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

This might also be helpful - [Passing values across pages ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592198/passing-values-across-pages-asp-net)